# curl under Windows Server 2022 uses UNIX certificate store when called in GitHub action

Tags: r, curl, github-actions, jags, rjags

I am using a [GitHub Action](https://github.com/r-lib/actions/blob/v2/examples/check-standard.yaml) in order to check an R package's functionality. In order to install a background dependeny (JAGS), I am using `curl.exe`:

```r
      - name: Install jags (Windows)
        if: runner.os == 'Windows'
        run: |
          curl.exe --ca-native -o wjags.exe --url https://deac-fra.dl.sourceforge.net/project/mcmc-jags/JAGS/4.x/Windows/JAGS-4.3.1.exe
          wjags.exe /S
          del wjags.exe
        shell: cmd
```

If I run the call to `curl.exe` on my local machine (Windows 11), I can download the file using curl without a problem, but on GitHub's Windows Server 2022, I get the following error:

> curl: (77) error setting certificate file: /usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
> operable program or batch file.

This appears to  be a UNIX file path to a certificate store. This surprises me as `curl.exe` is called under Windows, explicitly using the `--ca-native` option. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Tried to reproduce your issue but it's working fine for me. See https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/runs/8268657352/job/22622074139.

Comment: I can also no longer reproduce the error, even though we demonstrated it on several GitHub repositories in February. Apparently, the underlying issue was fixed.

Comment: Yes, looks like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the question was posted in February 2024, the problem was tested on multiple GitHub repositories. In March 2024, we could no longer reproduce it. The underlying issue has apparently been fixed.